# Java JDBC: Driver can't get connection to database

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am getting this error and I don't know how to fix it.

My code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection c = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
}
```

Here is list of all the errors appeared in the console:

```
Error:(28, 1) java: org.sqlite.Stmt is not abstract and does not override abstract method isCloseOnCompletion() in java.sql.Statement

Error:(45, 21) java: incompatible types: org.sqlite.core.DB cannot be converted to org.sqlite.DB

Error:(158, 25) java: incompatible types: org.sqlite.DB cannot be converted to org.sqlite.core.DB

Error:(214, 25) java: incompatible types: org.sqlite.DB cannot be converted to org.sqlite.core.DB

Error:(42, 7) java: org.sqlite.RS is not abstract and does not override abstract method <T>getObject(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<T>) in java.sql.ResultSet

Error:(34, 1) java: org.sqlite.MetaData is not abstract and does not override abstract method generatedKeyAlwaysReturned() in java.sql.DatabaseMetaData

Error:(35, 7) java: org.sqlite.PrepStmt is not abstract and does not override abstract method setNClob(int,java.io.Reader) in java.sql.PreparedStatement
```

Also Stmt.java class is opening so I guess I get these errors because of it.

I tried to add JDBC to project variables but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Which SQLite JDBC jar are you using? Try taking out the Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"). From https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/

Comment: The fact you get compilation errors for SQLite JDBC driver classes, suggests you copied the sources of the SQLite JDBC driver into your project instead of adding the JAR with compiled classes of the JDBC driver onto the classpath of your project.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: I forgot to add JDBC to project libraries. Thanks.